# d3 adding new key value to existing json data

Tags: javascript, d3.js, nvd3.js

I have a question that would like to seek your expertise on.

This is my JSON array that I have in:

```
[{
    key : "Group 0",
    values : [{
        x : 0.12817352913159197,
        y : 4.360475517778741,
        size : 0.8945912778023366
    }, {
        x : -1.8709283296311146,
        y : 1.4047025584603734,
        size : 0.3621509721039796
    }]
}, {
    key : "Group 1",
    values : [{
        x : 0.6574795166435595,
        y : -0.6037258352005531,
        size : 0.0942101986534386
    }, {
        x : -0.4951370796031603,
        y : -0.18739226817326712,
        size : 0.8843348380774309
    }]
}]
```

i am passing this to scatterChart so the data inside contain this, now i want to add shape to each values, finaly i want it like this to be in chart data:

```
[{
    key : "Group 0",
    values : [{
        x : 0.12817352913159197,
        y : 4.360475517778741,
        size : 0.8945912778023366,
        shape : "circle"
    }, {
        x : -1.8709283296311146,
        y : 1.4047025584603734,
        size : 0.3621509721039796,
        shape : "diamond"
    }]
}, {
    key : "Group 1",
    values : [{
        x : 0.6574795166435595,
        y : -0.6037258352005531,
        size : 0.0942101986534386,
        shape : "circle"
    }, {
        x : -0.4951370796031603,
        y : -0.18739226817326712,
        size : 0.8843348380774309,
        shape : "diamond"
    }]
}]
```

how to acheive this using d3 or nvd3?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly

```
var demo = [{
    key: "Group 0",
    values: [{
        x: 0.12817352913159197,
        y: 4.360475517778741,
        size: 0.8945912778023366,
    }, {
        x: -1.8709283296311146,
        y: 1.4047025584603734,
        size: 0.3621509721039796,
    }]
}, {
    key: "Group 1",
    values: [{
        x: 0.6574795166435595,
        y: -0.6037258352005531,
        size: 0.0942101986534386,
    }, {
        x: -0.4951370796031603,
        y: -0.18739226817326712,
        size: 0.8843348380774309,
    }]
}];

for (var i = 0, j = demo.length; i < j; i++) {
    group = demo[i]['values'];
    for (var x = 0, y = group.length; x < y; x++) {
        if (x == 0) {
            // Assuming the first is always circle
            group[x]['shape'] = "circle";
        } else {
            // Assuming the second is always diamond
            group[x]['shape'] = "diamond";
        }
    };
};

console.log(demo);
```

There is a working version [here](http://jsfiddle.net/shabeer90/UfARq/).

Hope it helps